# Docker, set Memory Limit for group of container

Tags: docker

I'm running a docker environment with roundabout 25 containers for my private use. My system has 32GB Ram.

Especially RStudio Server and JupyterLab often need a lot of memory.
So I limited the memory to for both container at 26 GB.

This works good as long not both application storing dataframes in memory. If now RServer stores some GB and Jupyter also is filling memory to the limit my system crashes.

Is there any way to configure that these two container together are allowed to use 26GB ram max.
Or a relative limit like Jupyter is allowed to use 90% of free memory.

As I'm working now with large datasets it can happen all the time that (because I forget to close a kernel or something else) the memory can increase to the limit and I want just the container to crash and not the whole system.
And I don't want lower the limit for Jupyter further as the biggest dataset on its own need 15 GB of memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the combination of --memory-reservation and --memory options for the docker run command. You may set the soft limit to 90% of 26 GB

Comment: But this doesn't prevent the two container from having together 32GB or don't I unterstand the function of these options correctly?

Comment: Actually you can manage them individually...will elaborate a bit more with concrete usage...in some time..